# how to insert a new record in a table that has foreign key attributes in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What is wrong in this statement since customers table has only one record

```
INSERT INTO CART (Cartid,custid,Pid)
VALUES ('2',SELECT(custid from CUSTOMERS), SELECT (Pid from Products where Pname ='shirts'))
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the cart table id is primary key and auto_increment. Get the customer id and store in a variable. You can try something similar like this

```
INSERT INTO CART (Cartid,custid,Pid) VALUES ('', SELECT custid from CUSTOMERS  WHERE custid = '$customer_id'),(SELECT Pid FROM Products WHERE Pname = 'shirts' LIMIT 1));
```

Comment: All the best. Go ahead

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO CART (Cartid, custid, Pid)
    VALUES (2,
            (SELECT custid FROM CUSTOMERS LIMIT 1),
            (SELECT Pid FROM Products WHERE Pname = 'shirts' LIMIT 1)
           );
```

Your parentheses are in the wrong place.

Notes:

- I added the `LIMIT` just to enforce that one row is returned.
- I removed the single quotes around `'2'`, because ids are usually number.
- You probably should not be inserting the id; it should be an auto-increment column.

Comment: not a full criticism of the answer as it corresponds to the question...more a general concern...it always gets the first customer (that's odd)...and assumes the product name is unique

Comment: That's not my question though

Comment: @Ctznkane525 . . . I didn't even both to check.  The OP uses this logic and is quite clear that the table has one row.